# How prove monotonicity of this function without using derivation?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want proof that the following function is strictly monotone (I need this proof to prove something else).
The problem is I may not use the first derivate because we have not discussed that in our readings yet.
It would make the work way easier but I'm not allowed to do it...

> $f(x) = x + \sqrt[5]{x} - \frac{1}{x}$

We have said that $f$ is monotonically decreasing (or monotonically increasing) if for all $x_{1}, x_{2} \in M$ with $x_{1} \leq x_{2}: f(x_{1}) \leq f(x_{2})$ (or $f(x_{1}) \geq  f(x_{2})$).

But we were not told what $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ stand for so I don't really know what to do with this formula.
It's really annoying we cannot just use the derivative :(

I could prove it I think if I knew what these two variables stand for, what I have to put into the function for these two variables?

Comment: The statement isn't true.

$f(-0.1)> f(0.1)$  It is only true, if you restrict the domain to one side of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that for any two numbers $x_1<x_2$ in the domain of the function you have $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$. If you want to use this (definition) to prove that your function is strictly increasing, then you need to do this for all $x_1 < x_2$. So let's say that we had two such numbers.

Then (you probably already know this) $x_1 < x_2$ and $\sqrt[5]{x_1} < \sqrt[5]{x_2}$ because both $x$ and $\sqrt[5]{x}$ are increasing functions.

Now then, if $x_1 < x_2$ then $\frac{1}{x_1} > \frac{1}{x_2}$. That means $-\frac{1}{x_1} < - \frac{1}{x_2}$ (at least for $x_1, x_2$ with the same sign.

Since all pieces have increased, you have $f(x_x) < f(x_2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I think I understood it! :-)
Only thing that might be a problem for me is the equal (smaller-equal / greater-equal) sign but let's see.

Comment: @berndgr: Ahh.... sorry, I didn't see that. You can replace all the strict inequalities by smaller than or equal to/ greater then or equal to. The analysis is the same.